# What is the difference between property closure and a method in Swift?

Tags: swift, methods, closures, difference

```
class Bartek {
    var name: String = "Bartek"
    var description: () -> String = {
         return "Person name is" + self.name
    }

    func description() -> String {
        return "Person name is" + name
    }
}
```

Now I can use it like that:

```
var bartek = Bartek()
bartek.description()
```

Actually which on do i use? What is the better? a property closure or a method? When to use them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Property closure can be optional and assignable. Example: `var description: (() -> String)?`
2. Property closure can capture variables (like `self` in your example). You have created a memory leak there.
3. If you implement protocols that defines a method, you must conform with method, not property closure.

Use property closure for strategy patterns where user of your object can change the behaviour. Use method in pretty much any other case.

Comment: where is a memory leak exactly?

Comment: `Bartek` instance has strong reference to `description` closure. `description` captures `self` and has strong reference to it (`Bartek` instance). Retain cycle is formed and object are not destroyed.

Comment: i know: `{
[unowned self] in
         return "Person name is" + self.name
    }`

Comment: Yes that is how you can avoid strong retain cycle there.

Answer (score 0):

Use a property if it's some (more or less) static information. Use a function to indicate that something is computed.